# Accessing dictionary key in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble accessing a dictionary. My code is:

```
if let deletedObjects: NSArray = noti.userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey] {

}
```

I get an error `Cannot subscript a value of type [NSObject : AnyObject]? with an index of type String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfo` of `NSNotification` is optional, so you have to unwrap it, e.g.:

```
if let deletedObjects = noti.userInfo?[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? NSArray {
    // use `deletedObjects` here
}
```